# issue opening html with check box control in word 2010

Tags: html, ms-word

i wrote an html with a check box saved it as .docx,

when opened using word 2010 the check boxes are shown as red x(both selected and selected), how can i fix this?

try to save and open the below html file in word doc

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="checkbox" value="myvalue1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="myvalue2" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="myvalue3" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="myvalue4" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="myvalue5" />
  <p>

    Test

  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is it that you are intending to do?

Comment: i would like to open the html with word doc  and be able to see the check box properly displayed the first two selected and the rest unselected..as of now all of the above 5 chkboxes  are shown as RED.   we have an application that generates alot of html files and saves them as .doc..when opened these files i see the checkbox issue

Comment: word is able to render and display all of the html tables and mark ups except for the check boxes..( while converting html to word are the html checkboxes supported by word?